# Why is my DataGrid not sorting?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

My DataGrid is not sorting. Clicking on the DataGrid header columns does not sort the DataGrid.

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dataList}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="key" headerText="Key"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="summary" headerText="Summary">
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

And the data provider:

```
<s:ArrayList id="dataList"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using an ArrayCollection and not an ArrayList.

This:

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="dataList"/>
```

Or this:

```
<s:XMLListCollection id="dataList"/>
```

Not this:

```
<s:ArrayList id="dataList"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. It says I have to wait two days.